# No-refresh sign up style

Tags: signup-signon

I'm developing an web site where the sign up flow has three steps. I'm deciding between two designs.

The first approach would be to have a single page, eg. `site.com/sign-up`, and use JavaScript to show the three different steps. This would have no page loads after the first one.

The second approach would be to have three different pages, eg. `sign.com/sign-up/step1`, then `sign.com/sign-up/step2`, etc. This would load each page separately. It enables the back button unlike the previous approach.

Is there a "best practice" approach here, or is it a case by case thing? What should I consider?

Comment: It depends whether the step sends server side request or not. if it does, you can't get away with refresh. By the way you can allow submitting details of all steps at the end of the last step. Speaking on behalf of user who wants to be member for little purpose, each refresh will be disliked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would personally go with AJAX wizard.

1. Using AJAX usually grants better performance because you won't have to reload the page over and over for each step, you would only be loading content for each step
2. Another performance increase would come from leveraging client side browser to render the steps, instead of relying on your server to compile the code and send it back to the browser for rendering (less network hops)
3. You don't have to worry about search engine robots indexing each step (as I am sure you don't want users to be able to land on step 2 by accident and bypass step 1

**NOTE:**

You should be able to implement "back" button regardless which route you take, it's just slightly more difficult to do so with AJAX solution.

Comment: Slightly more work, not slightly more difficult ;-)

Comment: :) it depends who you talk to... a developer or a designer ;)